# Как лучше кешировать, в файле или в базе

Tags: php, sql, кэширование

Как лучше кешировать данные?..

Есть сложный запрос, с несколькими LEFT JOIN, подзапросом, GROUP BY и LIMIT.

Есть в базе 1000записей, в одном запросе выводится 50 записей с учетом LIMIT 50, 0;

Сначала - я кэшировал все данные в файл (чем больше стало данных, тем дольше чтение файла) - и это меня отвергло от кэша в файл.

Но как тогда кэшировать данные, чтобы не грузить базу запросами?
Эти 1000строк результата, записывать может в базу в колонку cache, и оттуда тянуть данные? Но это же опять будет бред...

Подскажите, пожалуйста

Боюсь за нагрузку бд, ибо если сидит 100человек на сайте - это уже 100запросов к базе...

Почитал, что **файловый кэш использовать только при малых объемах данных**, получается необходимо использовать запросы к базе, но это же большая нагрузка на бд будет, и кэширование запросов не поможет, так как банально даже LIMIT записей будет разный.

Как в таком случае лучше кэшировать?

Comment: ставьте redis, memcache, memcached и не мучьтесь

Comment: @jashka посмотрю в их сторону, спасибо

Comment: Если хочется сделать "вручную" - кэшируйте не в файл, а во временную (уровня соединения) таблицу.

Comment: PS. На ENGINE = Memory.

Comment: О каких временах мы говорим? Сколько занимает запрос? Какие индексы используются в запросе если посмотреть его план? (`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`)

Comment: @user190134 посмотрите в сторону [zend-cache](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-cache/) Иcпользовать ли для кеширования Filesystem, Memcached, Memory или что-то другое — можете в ходе эксперимента изменять и выбрать, что для вас будет оптимальным. `файловый кэш использовать только при малых объемах данных` — вы это где-то на российских просторах прочитали? Что значит малые? Число 100, например? А если оно высчитывается час по какой-то постоянной формуле? И таких одинаковых расчетов в алготитме 100. Зачем каждый раз расчитывать, если можно закешировать?

Comment: @user190134 вопрос и решение вообще нужно начать с того, как вы вообще данные в БД храните, всё ли с индексами впорядке? Они вообще есть? Вы проводили уже анализ прежде чем задумываться о кешировании? **в одном запросе выводится 50 записей с учетом LIMIT 50, 0** — сколько по времени выполняется запрос? И т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @AlexanderBragin запрос выполняется быстро, если напрямую брать данные из базы, индексы проставлены. Но я и объясняю, что я хранил результаты в файле, и при весе в 100кб - время читаемости файла было больше, чем запрос в базу.

Comment: @user190134 при анализе только опцию [`SQL_NO_CACHE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-in-select.html) не забывайте «включать». Если у вас MySQL. И какая версия...

Comment: @user190134 «холодные/горячие» данные можно ещё давать такое определение) Но **быстро**, мы как инженеры, не должны так говорить) Быстро это сколько?) 20ms, 200ms, 2s?... Имело ли место тогда кешировать? Что вы добиться пытались, какую проблему решить?

Comment: @user190134 и ещё момент. Имеет ли место сейчас заниматься оптимизацией — какое у вас посещение сайта сейчас (или у вас API какой-нибудь)? Какое количество запросов в БД в минуту/секунду?.. _Боюсь за нагрузку бд, ибо если сидит 100человек на сайте - это уже 100запросов к базе..._ — у вас чат?

Answer (score 5):

Если у вас на сервере достаточно оперативной памяти, то кеш ограниченного набора данных в файле будет не медленнее кеша в памяти, потому что при повторных чтениях этого файла вы фактически будете брать данные из памяти без обращений к диску.

Если же у вас на сервере *мало* памяти, то тут мало какие оптимизации помогут. Подумайте, может +$10 в месяц на более мощный сервер принципиально решат вашу проблему?

Стоит кешировать не столько результаты запроса, а сколько готовый результат. Например, если в результате у вас на какой-то странице показывается кусок HTML, то именного его и нужно кешировать в файле или ещё где. Этим вы получите максимальную выгоду от кеша так как исключается необходимость парсинга. Прочитали файл, отдали клиенту, всё!

Где кешировать - вопрос удобства. Если у вас только один запрос, то и в файле удобно. Если у вас тысячи разных запросов, то memcached/redis  справятся с задачей с меньшим приложением усилий с вашей стороны.

Comment: именного его и нужно кешировать в файле или ещё где.
Вот в этом и вопрос, или еще где

Comment: Где удобно, там и кешируйте. Если у вас только один запрос, то и в файле удобно. Если у вас тысячи разных запросов, то memcached / redis лучше справятся с задачей.

Answer (score 4):

Если у вас проблемы с производительностью на тысяче записей и ста пользователях, то вы явно что-то делаете не так и нужно разбираться - что именно.

Реальные сайты работают на базах с сотнями тысяч и больше записей. Для показа одной страницы могут отправляться десятки запросов, которые могут возвращать многие тысячи строк - и всё это для десятков тысяч пользователей. Если на ваших масштабах у вас уже проблема с производительностью, то есть какая-то фундаментальная проблема, которую нужно найти.

Возможно, запрос сильно не оптимален. Попробуйте задать отдельный вопрос в котором приведите код запроса с просьбой помочь оптимизировать (в вопросе также нужно будет привести структуру вашей базы, количество строк в каждой таблице и сколько по времени сейчас занимает выполнение запроса.)

Возможно, вам просто нужно добавить индексы чтобы ускорить его выполнение.

Если всё-таки запрос действительно тяжёлый и улучшить его нельзя (или сервер слабенький), то действительно стоит подумать о кэшировании. В серьёзных базах для таких случаев существуют материализованные представления. По поводу мускула - не знаю, есть ли в нём такая штука, не работал с этой субд. Но даже если нет - то не проблема по расписанию или по событию пересоздавать таблицу с результатами запроса и работать уже с ней. В любом случае это будет лучше, чем хранить кэш в файле.

Answer (score 2):

Парсить файл в любом случае дольше чем идет запрос до БД, имхо.
А если БД на одном сервере с сайтом, то вообще отлично.

Comment: Да, бд на одном сервере с сайтом, но нагрузка то полюбому идет, и здесь нужно учитывать то, что помимо этого запроса еще и данные пользователя тянутся, аяксы... Выдержит ли мускул от одного пользователя столько запросо?

Comment: @user190134 почему бы и нет? Всяко лучше чем каждый запрос парсить данные с файла.

Comment: Да в том то и дело, что задумался об этом.

Comment: БД: сетевые издержки, (многократное) чтение с диска, издержки на обработку запроса. Файл: однократное чтение с диска, издержки на парсинг

Comment: @etki у БД пинг локали, выборка информации сразу с неё, скорость обработки ниже скорости обработки файла, в итоге при одинаково большом объеме данных БД справится лучше. П.с. файл придется перечитывать столько же раз сколько и нужно запросов, ведь автор вопроса писал, что идет очень много запросов от всех пользователей. (Возможно, что автор где-нибудь сравнивает результаты запросов пользователей или что-то в этом плане)

Comment: что значит сразу с нее? она ровно так же файлы читает

Comment: @etki обработка запроса идет на сервере мускула, который в свою очередь написан на си/си++, а он-то с этой задачей явно быстрее чем php справится...

Comment: это если бы он ровно так же читал файл от начала и до конца и парсил какой-нибудь json, а не разбирался с запросом.

Comment: @etki ясно, мсье, вас не переубедить, ну что же, удачи оставаться с вашей позицией касательно этого вопроса.